# Dynamically create empty EMF project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, emf

I want to create programmatically an empty EMF project using Java code. Basically the same setup one creates when using the GUI dialog to chose the option "Empty EMF Project" under the EMF category.

I already found [code snippets](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/05/eclipse-jdt-tutorial-java-model/) for creating Java projects. I cannot find anything for empty EMF projects. I suppose the functionality is buried somewhere in the JDT API or EMF API.

Comment: Why don't you create an empty EMF project using GUI first and then simply write the code to generate similar files?

Comment: You mean using an empty EMF project as prototype, and then simply dynamically import it as new project every time I need one? Seems like a solution, but more like a hacked one. Generating the project using the API would be more elegant I think. But if I cannot do it in another way I will use your idea.

Comment: You're right and it might not even work when you upgrade. But I guess it's the fastest. Another approach will be to check the source code to see how Maven, Gradle or AntEclipse is doing it.

Comment: I posted my solution as answer, maybe you are interested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing some [code](http://architecturware.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/architecturware/oaw_v4/core.plugin/plugin.oaw4/main/src/org/openarchitectureware/wizards/EclipseHelper.java?revision=1.13&view=markup) for generating Eclipse plug-in projects this is what I came up with:

```
package projectGenerator;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.ICommand;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IContainer;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException;

public abstract class EMFProjectGenerator {

    public static IProject createProject(String projectName) {
        IProject project = null;
        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
        int version = 2;
        String finalName = projectName;
        project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(projectName);
        while (project.exists()) { // to avoid duplicates:
            finalName = projectName + version;
            version++;
            project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(finalName);
        }
        IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
        IProjectDescription projectDescription = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(finalName);
        projectDescription.setLocation(null);
        try {
            project.create(projectDescription, null);
        } catch (CoreException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<IClasspathEntry> classpathEntries = new ArrayList<IClasspathEntry>();
        projectDescription.setNatureIds(new String[] { JavaCore.NATURE_ID, "org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature" });
        ICommand java = projectDescription.newCommand();
        java.setBuilderName(JavaCore.BUILDER_ID);
        ICommand manifest = projectDescription.newCommand();
        manifest.setBuilderName("org.eclipse.pde.ManifestBuilder");
        ICommand schema = projectDescription.newCommand();
        schema.setBuilderName("org.eclipse.pde.SchemaBuilder");
        ICommand oaw = projectDescription.newCommand();
        projectDescription.setBuildSpec(new ICommand[] { java, manifest, schema, oaw });
        IFolder srcContainer = null;
        try {
            project.open(null);
            project.setDescription(projectDescription, null);
            srcContainer = project.getFolder("src");
            if (!srcContainer.exists()) {
                srcContainer.create(false, true, null);
            }
        } catch (CoreException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        IClasspathEntry srcClasspathEntry = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(srcContainer.getFullPath());
        classpathEntries.add(0, srcClasspathEntry);
        classpathEntries.add(JavaCore.newContainerEntry(
                new Path("org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7")));
        classpathEntries.add(JavaCore.newContainerEntry(new Path("org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins")));
        try {
            javaProject.setRawClasspath(classpathEntries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[classpathEntries.size()]), null);
            javaProject.setOutputLocation(new Path("/" + finalName + "/bin"), null);
        } catch (JavaModelException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        createManifest(finalName, project);
        return project;
    }

    private static IFile createFile(String name, IContainer container, String content, String charSet) throws CoreException, IOException {
        IFile file = container.getFile(new Path(name));
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(file.getCharset()));
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.setContents(stream, true, true, null);
        } else {
            file.create(stream, true, null);
        }
        stream.close();
        if (file != null && charSet != null) {
            file.setCharset(charSet, null);
        }
        return file;
    }

    private static void createManifest(String projectName, IProject project) {
        StringBuilder manifestContent = new StringBuilder("Manifest-Version: 1.0\n");
        manifestContent.append("Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2\n");
        manifestContent.append("Bundle-Name: " + projectName + "\n");
        manifestContent.append("Bundle-SymbolicName: " + projectName + "; singleton:=true\n");
        manifestContent.append("Bundle-Version: 1.0.0\n");
        manifestContent.append("Require-Bundle: ");
        manifestContent.append(" org.eclipse.emf.ecore\n");
        IFolder metaInf = project.getFolder("META-INF");
        try {
            metaInf.create(false, true, null);
            createFile("MANIFEST.MF", metaInf, manifestContent.toString(), null);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It is not perfect, but should do for now. If anyone has some improvements to this please feel free to tell me!